# unable to uncheck and check single item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a list of items with checkbox. When checkbox of any item is clicked, certain action(add, delete, move etc) is shown to apply those action to that selected item. Also i could implement the check all button to check all the items and also uncheck it. But if i check for one item, all item gets checked and same when unchecking.

**Here is my code**

```
    var Device = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
      return {
        checked: []
      }
    },

    handleChange(e, key) {
      let checked = this.state.checked.slice();
      if (e.target.checked) {
        checked.push(key);
        console.log('checked before removing', checked);
      }
      else {
        checked.splice(checked.indexOf(key), 1);
        console.log('checked after removing', checked);
        // checked.filter((x, i) => checked.splice(checked.indexOf(key), 1));
      }
      this.setState({ checked: checked });
    },

    checkAll() {
      this.setState({
        checked: this.props.devices.entrySeq().map(([key, value]) => key)
      }).toArray();
    },

    uncheckAll() {
      this.setState({ checked: [] });
    },

    render() {
        const { checked } = this.state;
        let devices = this.props.devices.entrySeq().map(([key, value]) => {
        let url = '/device/'+value.get('id');
        let name = value.get('name');
        return (
          <RowGroup key={key}>
              <Row>
                <Cell>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    name={name}
                    checked={checked.indexOf(key) !== -1}
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, key)}
                   />
                </Cell>
                <RouterLink to={url}>
                  <Cell>
                    {name}
                  </Cell>
                </RouterLink>
              </Row>
        </RowGroup>
        );
      }).toArray();

      return (
        <div>
          { checked.length !== 0 ? <DeviceActions uncheckAll={() => this.uncheckAll()} /> :
             <GlobalDeviceActions
               checkAll={() => this.checkAll()}
               uncheckAll={() => this.uncheckAll()}
             />
           }
        <Table>
            {devices}
        </Table>
        </div>
      );
    },
});

const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
  return {};
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  devices: selectDevices()
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Device);


const DeviceActions = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Actions>
      <Uncheck onClick={props.uncheckAll} />
      <Add />
      <Move />
    </Actions>
  </div>
);

export const GlobalDeviceActions = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Actions>
      <Check onClick={props.checkAll} />
      <Uncheck onClick={props.uncheckAll} />
    </Actions>
  </div>
);

export default DeviceActions;
```

**With Updated code from @Jonny Buchanan, everything is working fine but when all the items are checked at once, i cannot uncheck single items. I can only uncheck whole items at once.**

**UPDATE**

It is now working. in checkAll function i have to convert collection to array. I guess, its because collection is generator which does not execute right away so i have to mutate it to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep a list of checked items in state, `checkAll()` can set all the available item keys/ids (or whatever's most appropriate to put in that list) and `uncheckAll()` can just set it to an empty list.

```
getInitialState() {
  return {
    checked: [],
  }
},

handleChange(e, key) {
  let checked = this.state.checked.slice();
  if (e.target.checked) {
    checked.push(key);
  }
  else {
    checked.splice(checked.indexOf(key), 1);
  }
  this.setState({ checked });
},

checkAll() {
  this.setState({
    checked: this.props.devices.entrySeq().map(([key, value]) => key)
  });
},

uncheckAll() {
  this.setState({ checked: [] });
},
```

Then in `render()` you can derive `checked` per-input:

```
             <input
                type="checkbox"
                name={name}
                checked={checked.indexOf(key) !== -1}
                onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, key)}
               />
```

Comment: How can i show GlobalDeviceActions when no any item is checked which you can see in my code?

Comment: You can check the `.length` of the array for that in render. `=== 0`: nothing is checked, `=== the length of your list of things`, everything is checked.

Comment: when i check all the items and try to uncheck any one selected item, the item does not get unchecked. Is this mutable issue?

Comment: is not splice mutable way?